# Having trouble getting a number from an AJAX request to a javascript variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm attempting to make a chart that displays the CPU percentage on a page, and auto-updates along with the CPU percent as it changes. I'm having issues understanding how to get information back from the PHP script once the AJAX request has been sent. Ideally I'd like to be able to use the variable '$cpuPercent' and have in the  '.update();' part of my update function.

I've tried having the php code within the update function and echoing the $cpuPercent, but it does not update each time, as it'll only run once, and keep using the same number each time it updates.

Here is the php from my system_actions.php script.

```
exec('wmic cpu get loadpercentage', $output2);
$cpuPercent = $output2[1];
echo json_encode($cpuPercent);
```

Here is my javascript

```
function getUsage(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'system_actions.php?action=cpu',
        async: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'post',
        success:function(output){
            var cpuPercent = parseInt(output);
            document.getElementById('cpu').value = cpuPercent;
            updateChart();
        }
    })
}
setInterval(getUsage, 2500);

function updateChart(){
    var link = document.getElementById('randombutton');
    link.click();
}

  $('.updatePieCharts').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    charts.each(function() {
      var number = parseInt(document.getElementById('cpu').value);
      $(this).data('easyPieChart').update(number);
    });
  });
```

I definitely feel a disconnect in how it all works together, but I can't quite figure it out. Any help or a point in the right direction would be great. Back to google I go.

Comment: Your AJAX url uses a GET query string, but you're specifying POST in the options. This probably isn't your problem, but you should pick one or the other.

Comment: I believe he needs to format the array according to a JSON specification for this to work. I would do in the PHP: `echo json_encode(array( "cpu_percent" => $cpuPercent ));` and then in the Javascript use it like: `var cpuPercent = parseInt(output.cpu_percent);`. Maybe the PHP script wasn't returning a valid JSON, but the AJAX call specifies the `dataType: 'json'` line, so it needs to be valid. Just guessing anyway, but doesn't JSON work like a dictionary (key-value pairs) or an array itself? Does it work with single values? Just asking, good luck.

Comment: Note that your script should have worked if you have specified `dataType: 'text'` instead of `dataType: 'json'`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your PHP script is returning JSON, the `output` variable in your `success` callback will be either a JavaScript object or array. Either way, you can't really use `parseInt` on it, so `var cpuPercent` is probably never getting set to anything useful.

If you post some sample output of your PHP script, we can tell you how to locate the number you're looking for.

Comment: if I go to the php script, it outputs:   "0"  on the screen. if I inspect element, it shows   ""0""   all I need is the number, really. Can I echo the value back as a string rather than JSON?

Comment: Of course; just stop `json_encode`ing it, and fetch the data as text instead of as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false
})
```

And also you can try toggling your async option to false too.

I think this flot example may help you.
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html